# Parse error for retina @media query nested within another @media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I've read that nesting @media queries within other @media queries is perfectly valid within CSS3.

However, I am receiving a parse error via the CSS validator for the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .some-class {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
        .retina-class {
            background: url(images/image@2x.png);
            background-size: 200px 200px;
        }
    } 
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not totally sure but i think you missed an "and" in second media query

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .some-class {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
        .retina-class {
            background: url(images/image@2x.png);
            background-size: 200px 200px;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I found the snippet via CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query. The most recent example (at the top) doesn't use "and". Your code also flags a parse error via the validator.